# Use matplolib in Jupyter Notebook and Cannot Display Figure in the Proper Way

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

started to learn using matplotlib to create graphs. But I tried various plots and they are all displaying in a wired way. I can only see the top left corner of a figure. I tried Chrome and Microsoft Edge. Both of them had the same issue. Here is an example of what I got:
[I only see the top left cornor of the figure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om1pz.png)

Comment: This was a known bug with Matplotlib 3.3.0 and has been fixed in 3.3.1 (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/18142)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that should definately work in Jupyter.  If this code plots properly, then there is probably nothing wrong with your software.  Give this code a try and see what happens.

```
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt  
    
    x = [5, 2, 9, 4, 7]   
    y = [10, 5, 8, 4, 2]  
    
    plt.hist(y)  
      
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Gray. It works properly. I can see the whole figure. But do you have any idea what I should do if I also want to see other figures? Thanks so much!